# How do we determine the marginal mean using the joint PDF?

Tags: expected-value

I'm reading chapter 4 of DeGroot and either I missed it or he didn't explain it but I am not seeing how, given a joint distribution f(X, Y), how do we find E[X] and E[Y].  I have learned how to find E[r(X, Y)] where r(X, Y) is a real function involving X and Y.  But I don't know how to find E[X] and E[Y] give f(X, Y).  Do we just treat one or the other as a constant and just $\int x f(X, Y) dx$?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your suggested approach would find the *conditional* mean of, in this case, $X$ given $Y$, typically written $\mathbb{E}[X|Y]$.  In order to find the *marginal* mean, we need to integrate $Y$ out of the expression $\mathbb{E}[X|Y]$ (this is known as the Law of Iterated Expectation, see for example https://brilliant.org/wiki/law-of-iterated-expectation/.)

This integration can be written:

$$\begin{split}
\mathbb{E}[X] = \mathbb{E}_Y[\mathbb{E}[X|Y]] &=& \int_Y\mathbb{E}[X|Y=y]f(y)dy \\ &=& 
\int_Y\left[\int_Xxf(x|y)dx \right] f(y)dy\\
&=&\int_Y\int_Xxf(x,y)dxdy
\end{split}$$

where the last step follows from $f(x,y) = f(x|y)f(y)$.